# Using GSAP (TweenMax) on css varabiles

Tags: gsap, css-variables

I'm really into Google's Polymer and I love GSAP - and so far I've been using the two in conjunction without a hitch. Unfortunately I have now hit a problem - how do I use GSAP (TweenMax to be specific) with custom css variables? 

**For example:** 

To change `someCssProperty` of `someElement` I would 
`TweenMax.to(someElement, 1, someCssProperty: "value");` 
but the `someCssProperty` becomes an issue when I'm trying to animate a css variable, which take on the form `--some-custom-css-variable` .
I have tried to use 
`TweenMax.to(someElement, 1, --some-custom-css-Property: "value");` 
(obviously gives me errors) and I also tried to use
 `TweenMax.to(someElement, 1, "--some-custom-css-Property": "value");` 

(quotes around the `some-custom-Css-property`) - however this results in 
no change/animation and an `invalid tween value` error message on the developer console.

**So the question is:**  how would I go about animating custom css variables with TweenMax (GSAP)?

Thanks for any help :)

**EDIT:**

I have tried using classes through

```
TweenMax.to("SomeElement", 5, {className:"class2"});
```

But this changed the element style as if I had declared it in css with a

```
SomeElement:hover {}
```

style (as in it does not animate, just changes immediately)

Comment: I couldn't find anything related to `css variables` in `GSAP` `cssPlugin` so not sure if it supports custom variable. [GreenSock forum](http://greensock.com/forums/forum/11-gsap/) should be the best place to ask about the support. But you can try with assigning different class to update the properties. You might need to use `updateStyles` or `native css support` for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, you're going to have to manually update the variable using a generic object.

```js
var docElement = document.documentElement;

var tl = new TimelineMax({ repeat: -1, yoyo: true, onUpdate: updateRoot });
var cs = getComputedStyle(docElement, null);

var blur = {
  value: cs.getPropertyValue("--blur")
};

tl.to(blur, 2, { value: "25px" });

function updateRoot() {
  docElement.style.setProperty("--blur", blur.value);
}
```

```css
:root {
  --blur: 0px;
}

img {
  -webkit-filter: blur(var(--blur));
  filter: blur(var(--blur));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.4/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/" />
```